# Creating a web application with java

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications

I have been trying for the past week or so to wrap my head around how I would go about creating a web application using java. I have looked into many services such as Vaadin, GWT, and CUBA, but because I don't really know which I need I haven't had much luck. Here is what I need:

- Web application framework in java (I don't know HTML or Javascript)
- Ability to use polymer elements

I would also prefer a minimized use of XML files, but I could work with them if need be.

Comment: Just a side note: you won't go far (or fast) without knowing HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript; so choose wisely.

Answer (score 0):

The Java framework for web development is J2EE.  It provides a Web Container to run web application (.war file) as well as other stuff.

Web application can be servlet, JSP etc.

If you are not familiar with Java Web Application, you may want to start with using Eclipse.  The following video shows how to use eclipse to build a project for web application

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av6zh817QEc

Answer (score 0):

Since one criteria is to use Polymer I recommend having a look at

[gwtmaterialdesign](http://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#!gettingstarted)

there are already a few tutorials how to get started and also ready to use templates.
Anyway I believe that you've to [dig a little into GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html) ...